# Setting flash variables not from VB

Tags: actionscript-3, vbscript, flashvars

I'm new in AS 3.0.
I'm trying to pass flash variables to SWF file from my VB application.
It worked in AS 2.0 using:
SetVariable method of ShockwaveFlash object but it doesnt' work in AS 3.0.
Any idea how can I do it
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the VB interface works, but how are you accessing the variables you are trying to set? How did it work in AS2?

I would guess you'd access them through

```
var myvar = root.loaderInfo.parameters["variableName"]
```

Comment: Exactly.
I just need to send 2 secret keys to SWF application.
I thought to do this using flash variables, but it doesn't work from Vb
If I use sockets I afraid firewall can block request.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an old thread on the [Kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/) forum that discusses many options for this:
[Using SetVariable with AS3 - Its ridiculous](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?289313-Using-SetVariable-with-AS3-Its-ridiculous).

(That thread name is awesome, I must say). Hope it helps!

EDIT:
After reading the thread myself, this seems to be the answer they arrived to:

```
use FlashVars="xxx=yyy" instead of SetVariable("xxx","yyy")
you can pick it up inside Flash with
root.loaderInfo.parameters.xxx
```